# If we have multiple redirect uris then which one will picked after Azure AD login

Tags: authentication, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I have web application and doing development in local machine. It's implemented with Azure Ad login. After login the application should redirect to local page. When it is published to App Service in test slot and when I login to app after that it should redirect test slot uri. Here the problem is, after login to Azure Ad for test slot url, it is redirecting to localhost uri. So user not able no move next.

I registered two uri's in Azure AD>App service registration>Authentication>redirect uris in azure portal.One is development uri which is https://localhost:44321 and another one is test uri.

Comment: Your app should specify the redirect URL to use with `redirect_uri=the-url-you-want` in the authentication redirect :)

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure your app's url as the redirect_uri in the Azure AD app.

And in your project, set the same url for redirecting after logging in.

You can customize the redirect uri as what you want and use it.